Grades and Attendance form POST data didn't save to the database
I'm currently working on a project where I have to input Grades and Attendance of students using Django. I have the forms for both Grades and Attendance but when I tried submitting it, it didn't show in their specific tables (Grade) and (Attendance). Can anyone help me?
This is my views.py for both:
 @login_required
    def mark_attendance(request):
        students = Student.objects.all()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = AttendanceForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('attendance')
        else:
            form = AttendanceForm()
        return render(request, 'mark_attendance.html', {'form': form, 'students': students})
    
    @login_required
    def input_grades(request):
        students = Student.objects.all()
        subjects = Subject.objects.all()
        form = GradesForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = GradesForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('grades')
            else:
                print(form.errors)  # This will print errors in the console
        return render(request, 'input_grades.html', {'form': form, 'students': students, 'subjects': subjects})

Here's my forms.py for both:
# Attendance Form
class AttendanceForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Attendance
            fields = ['student', 'date', 'is_present']
            widgets = {
                'date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
            }

# Grades Form
class GradesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Grades
        fields = ['student', 'subject', 'quarter', 'grade']
        widgets = {
            'grade': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'student': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'subject': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'quarter': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }

Forms in their html files:

mark_attendance.html


<div class="content">
      <h2>Mark Attendance</h2>
        <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="student">Student:</label>
                <select id="student" name="student">
                <option value="">Select Student</option>
                    {% for student in students %}
                    <option value="{{ student.id }}">{{ student.first_name }} {{ student.last_name }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="date">Date:</label>
                <input type="date" id="date" name="date">
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="is_present">Present:</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="is_present" name="is_present">
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>


input_grades.html
<div class="content">
      <h2>Input Grades</h2>
          <form method="post">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="student">Student:</label>
                      <select id="student" name="student">
                          <option value="">Select Student</option>
                          {% for student in students %}
                          <option value="{{ student.id }}">{{ student.first_name }} {{ student.last_name }}</option>
                          {% endfor %}
                      </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
                      <select id="subject" name="subject">
                          <option value="">Select Subject</option>
                          {% for subject in subjects %}
                          <option value="{{ subject.id }}">{{ subject.subject_name }}</option>
                          {% endfor %}
                      </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="quarter">Quarter:</label>
                      <select id="quarter" name="quarter">
                          <option value="">Select Quarter</option>
                          <option value="Q1">Q1</option>
                          <option value="Q2">Q2</option>
                          <option value="Q3">Q3</option>
                          <option value="Q4">Q4</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="grade">Grade:</label>
                      <input type="text" id="grade" name="grade">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
  </div>




By defining the HTML for your form yourself, i t means you can not easily know the form errors, at least not for the Attendance form. What errors does the form for the grades print?

There are no errors printed whenever I submit something. It's just nothing has been saved to the database.
